# Удаление класса при наведении

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Здравствуйте! Есть блок у которого изначально есть внутренняя тень(inset). Так же внутри этого блока есть кнопка, которая скрыта с помощью класса `.dspNone`. Необходимо чтобы при наведении на блок, тень внутри блока исчезла, а кнопка появилась(для этого я так понимаю необходимо удалить класс `.dspNone` у кнопки). На данный момент получилось сделать следующее,при наведении тень пропадает, но кнопка почему-то не появляется. Или это по другому делается?

```css
.block:hover {
  box-shadow: none;
}

.dspNone {
  display: none;
}

.block {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 99999px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) inset;
}

.block {
  background: red;
}

.block:hover > .btn1 {
  display: block;
}

.block:hover > .text {
  display: none;
}

.text
{
  padding-top:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block" style="width: 50px; height: 50px">
  <p class="text">TextText</p>
  <button class="dspNone btn1">Кнопка</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно сделать на css, так :

```
.block:hover > .btn1 {
  display: block;
}
```

Если же все-таки нужен jquery :

```js
$(".block").hover(function() {
  $('.btn1').removeClass("dspNone");
});

$(".block").mouseleave(function() {
  $('.btn1').addClass("dspNone");
});
```

```css
.block:hover {
  box-shadow: none;
}

.dspNone {
  display: none;
}

.block {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 99999px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) inset;
}

.block {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block" style="width: 50px; height: 50px">
  <button class="dspNone btn1">Кнопка</button>
</div>
```

По комментарию и уточнениям в вопросе, я смог сделать так (нарыл на [enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79461/vertical-alignment-of-elements-in-a-div)):

```css
.block:hover {
  box-shadow: none;
}

.dspNone {
  display: none;
}

.block {
  width: 60px;
  height: 50px;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 99999px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) inset;
}

.block {
  background: red;
}

.block:hover>.btn1 {
  display: block;
}

.block:hover>.text {
  display: none;
}

.text {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <p class="text">TextText</p>
  <button class="dspNone btn1">Кнопка</button>
</div>
```

Comment: уже навел мышку, чтобы проголосовать, но увидел фразу "как-то так", которая меня бесит, и не стал :)

Comment: Все круто. Спасибо! Решил обойтись только css. Теперь такой вопрос, до того как мы навели мышку, внутри блока находится текст, как только наводим текст пропадает и появляется кнопка(что уже реализовано). Пробовал применить ваш метод `.block:hover > .text {
  display: none;}` , но в этом случае все плывет(

Comment: нужно больше деталей и желательно пример кода

Comment: Добавил в свой код. Необходимо чтобы и текст и кнопка были на одном и том же уровне

Comment: @r.mcreal я немного обновил ответ